# Aggregate using weighted mean

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

I am trying to calculate average age of each US county weighted by the population of each age group in my data.

My data set looks like this:

```
state                  county    age    population   
   AL                 Autauga      1       2366         
   AL                 Autauga      2       3029         
   AL                 Autauga      3       3619          
   AL                 Autauga      4       3043          
   AL                 Autauga      5       3776
```

I'm trying to run something like this:

```
agedata <- aggregate(data$age, list(data$state, data$county), weighted.mean(data$age, data$population))
```

Whenever I run this command I get the following error:

> Error in match.fun(FUN) :    'weighted.mean(fulldata$age,
>   fulldata$population)' is not a function, character or symbol

Comment: `data %>% 
    group_by(state, county) %>% 
    summarize(weighted.mean(age, population))`

Comment: You can use `by`, i.e. `by(df, list(df$state, df$country), function(i) weighted.mean(i$Age, i$population))`

Comment: aggregate(.~state+country,df,weighted.mean)

Comment: @Onyambu `county` not `country`

Comment: `agedata <- aggregate( cbind( data$age, data$population), list(data$state, data$county), weighted.mean)`